# Should questions related to government surveillance programs be tagged with [surveillance]

Tags: discussion, tagging

Right now, there are a few questions on the subject, including:

- [Single point of failure: can US government requests for passwords be a vector for attack?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39586/single-point-of-failure-can-us-government-requests-for-passwords-be-a-vector-fo)
- [Is there any security benefit of not using email services recently associated with PRISM?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38588/is-there-any-security-benefit-of-not-using-email-services-recently-associated-wi)
- [What are the implications of NSA surveillance on the average internet user?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37076/what-are-the-implications-of-nsa-surveillance-on-the-average-internet-user)

Should they be tagged [surveillance](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surveillance)? What are the alternatives/synonyms?

Comment: Is the [tag:treasonous-lies] tag not enough for you?

Comment: Sorry- couldn't help myself. Too easy. And, on a tangentially related note, could we have a [tag:treasonous-lies] tag? There are more bad jokes I'd like to make, and they fall under no other category.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think Yes. It is a broad enough field that it makes sense, and if we already have at least these three questions we will get more (I think we already have more, to be honest)

Comment: Upvoted :) (just to get back to zero)